# how to make border length fix 20px from text instead of dynamic width according to screen size css3

Tags: css, text, border

and sorry I can't properly translate my question into easier language, sorry :(

```
body 
{
  background: #33ffcc;
  min-height: 100%; 
  margin-top: 3em;

}

#kal
{
font-size: 2em;
color: #fff;
border: 3px solid #fff;
text-align: center;
}
```

but here:
http://jsfiddle.net/skinnytotoro/s3Xfp/

and notice the box border is changing everytime the screen size change?
and I want to make the border is fixed, like, 20px from left and right of the text
is there how and any way to do so..?
thanks in advance!
sorry grammar errors too. Hope you don't get headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` and set `padding` to how much space you want: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Xfp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way to get this working would be to set a fixed size div with margins to center the div, then manually set the padding.

```
#kal {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s3Xfp/6/